# deadlock and synchronization in java

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

I have a question, I am always asked this in the interviews multiple times--

How is synchronization  implemented in java..
I have answered--
using trylock() mechanism
using wait, notify ,and notifyAll() methods in java
using synchronized blocks
using synchronized for class and object level
using mutexes for synchronization
using re-entrant locks

Are there any better answers to this?/

Comment: Are you talking about how synchronization is implemented by JVM implementors, or how synchronization is used by developers?

Answer (score 1):

If you care about gaining a deep insight on concurrency then a great source is the http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/ book.

If you simply care about "passing" this question in interview(s?) then http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html may do, but still you generally need to practice a bit to understand synchronization so you are in a position where you'll sufficiently answer questions following the extremely vague "How is synchronization implemented in java".

Comment: +1 - Buy the book and read it, and you'll be able to do more than answer interview questions.

Answer (score 0):

Why not read up on [Sun's/Oracle's tutorial on Java synchronization](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)? That's the official view.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with something along the lines of what is found here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html